# How to browse for video files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video, file-io

```
clc    
clear all    
[filename, user_canceled] = imgetfile    
[x,map]=imread(filename);    
imshow(x);    
imwrite(x,'imadiate.jpg')
```

I do this to browse for image files in MATLAB. How can I browse for video files?

Comment: Please learn how to ask questions properly.

Answer (score 1):

Get the file name and path with [UIGETFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uigetfile.html), then pass them to video reading function:

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile( ...
    {'*.avi;*.mpg;*.mpeg','Video Files (*.avi,*.mpg,*.mpeg)';
     '*.*',  'All Files (*.*)'}, ...
     'Select a video file');
mov = aviread(fullfile(pathname,filename));
```

[AVIREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/aviread.html) does not read much video formats. Better to use [VideoReader](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/videoreaderclass.html) class instead:

```
mov = VideoReader(fullfile(pathname,filename));
```